# Issue with array reduce not summing values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am attempting to sum an element of my array however the object is loading undefined. Any assistance would be appreciated. The scripts are below

I have tried using other methods like for each but it is not summing the appropriate numbers.

```
function sum()
{
    var totalMiles = flights.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
          return {
            miles: previousValue.milesElem + currentValue.milesElem,
          }
        });
//         flights.forEach( data => totalMiles = totalMiles + data.miles);
     document.getElementById('totalMiles').innerHTML = totalMiles;
//         return totalMiles;    
}
```

Here's all my code:

```js
var flights = [];
var totalMiles;

function add() {
  const numberElem = document.getElementById("number");
  const milesElem = document.getElementById("miles");
  if (flights.includes(numberElem.value)) {
    alert("Duplicates aren't allowed!")
  } else {
    flights.push({
      number: numberElem.value,
      miles: milesElem.value
    });
    render();
    numberElem.value = "";
    milesElem.value = "";
    sum();
  }
}

function render() {
  const tbody = document.querySelector('#outputTable tbody');
  tbody.innerHTML = flights.map((flight, i) => {
    return '' +
      '<tr>' +
      '<td>' +
      flight.number +
      '</td>' +
      '<td>' +
      flight.miles +
      '</td>' +
      '</tr>';
  }).join('');
}

function calculateStatus() {

  if (totalMiles < 9999) {
    tr = document.getElementById("table").rows[1];
    tr.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }

  if (totalMiles >= 10000 && totalMiles <= 24999) {
    tr = document.getElementById("table").rows[2];
    tr.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }

  if (totalMiles >= 25000) {
    tr = document.getElementById("table").rows[3];
    tr.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}

function sum() {
  var totalMiles = flights.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
    return {
      miles: previousValue.milesElem + currentValue.milesElem,
    }
  });
  //         flights.forEach( data => totalMiles = totalMiles + 
  data.miles);
document.getElementById('totalMiles').innerHTML = totalMiles;
//         return totalMiles;    
}

function refreshPage() {
  window.location.reload();
}
```

I am expecting the sum of flights.miles to be summed into the variable totalMiles

Comment: You are pushing *strings* in `flights`. You need to convert them to numbers. It's a common mistake...

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle so we can play around your script? Or can you post here your HTML as well?

Comment: completely forgot arrays push in strings! thank you!  would it be better to parse them in the render or can i wait to the sum function do you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your HTML, it is not possible to know whether you have some errors related to it, but in the code you shared there are the following issues:

- You have a global `totalMiles` and local `totalMiles` variable. That means whatever you assign to the local variable will not get into the global variable. As you reference the global variable elsewhere (`calculateStatus`), avoid using `var` where you put the `reduce` result in `totalMiles`.
- Because your `reduce` callback returns an object, the overall return value of `reduce` will not be a number, but an object. But you want it to be a number... So don't let the callback return an object, but a number.
- You are summing up a `milesElem` property, but that property is never defined. I assume you intended the `miles` property, so this point together with the previous points, is corrected by changing the `reduce` code to this (again, no `var` here!):

  ```
  totalMiles = flights.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
      return previousValue + currentValue.miles; // not milesElem
  }, 0); // provide initial value
  ```
- The `miles` property is however not numeric, so `+` would perform a string concatenation. To avoid that, make sure to assign a *number* to the `miles` property. You can use the unary plus to make the conversion:

  ```
  flights.push({
    number: +numberElem.value,  // <--- 
    miles: +milesElem.value     // <--- note the additional plus!
  });
  ```

Comment: trincot, thank you so much for the help here. I appreciate it very much. It all makes sense now with those 4 points considered. I realized "miles" was being stored as a string but with the other things considered it makes sense now

Answer (score -1):

Having looked closer at your code I spotted two problems. First, you are passing `milesElem.value` as string but it should be a number. You just have to pass this value as `Number(milesElem.value)`.

**EDIT:** I suppose the `numberElem.value` is also expected to be a number, so it should be converted to number just like `milesElem.value`. Moreover, since `flights` is an array of objects, you cannot just check if it includes a primitive value `flights.includes(numberElem.value)`. This needs to be rewritten as given below.

```
function add() {
  const numberElem = document.getElementById("number");
  const milesElem = document.getElementById("miles");
  const number = Number(numberElem.value);
  if (flights.includes(flight => flight.number === number)) {
    alert("Duplicates aren't allowed!")
  } else {
    flights.push({
      number: number,
      miles: Number(milesElem.value)
    });
    render();
    numberElem.value = "";
    milesElem.value = "";
    sum();
  }
}
```

In `sum()` function you should refer to `miles` property, not `milesElem`.

```
function sum() {
  var totalMiles = flights.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
    return previousValue + currentValue.miles;
  }, data.miles);
  document.getElementById("totalMiles").innerHTML = totalMiles;
}
```

Comment: i dont know about the downvote, but the result is "NaN". i am trying to think of a way to parse it now. I originally forgot to consider arrays parse out as strings.

Comment: I edited the answer. Check if the problem is solved now.